# No unique index found for the referenced field of the primary table

Tags: sql

When I run the booking table, it show the message "No unique index found for the referenced field of the primary table".

Create Table Customer

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
(
CUSTID               INTEGER NOT NULL,
FNAME             CHAR(18) NOT NULL,
LNAME            CHAR(18) NOT NULL,
STREET                CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
CITY                 CHAR(18) NOT NULL,
PROVINCE             CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
COUNTRY              CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
POSTCODE                CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
GENDER CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (CUSTID)
);
```

Create Table Booking

```
CREATE TABLE BOOKING 
(
BKGNO               INTEGER NOT NULL,
CUSTID               INTEGER NOT NULL,
FNO                    INTEGER NOT NULL,   
STATUSID           CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
CLASSID             CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
ORIG                  CHAR(18) NOT NULL,
DEST                   CHAR(18),
DEPTTIME           DATE NOT NULL,
ARRTIME            DATE NOT NULL,
BKGCITY             CHAR(18) NOT NULL,
PAIDBY               CHAR(18) NOT NULL,
FPRICE               CURRENCY NOT NULL,
TOTPRICE           CURRENCY NOT NULL,
PAIDAMT            CURRENCY NOT NULL,
BAL                     CURRENCY NOT NULL,
BKGDATE            DATE NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (BKGNO),
INDEX (ORIG,DEST,DEPTTIME, ARRTIME),
INDEX (CUSTID),
FOREIGN KEY (CUSTID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER,
FOREIGN KEY (FNO) REFERENCES FLIGHT_AVAILABILITY(FNO),
FOREIGN KEY(DEST) REFERENCES FLIGHT_AVAILABILITY(DEST),
FOREIGN KEY(DEPTTIME) REFERENCES FLIGHT_AVAILABILITY(DEPTTIME),
FOREIGN KEY(ARRTIME) REFERENCES FLIGHT_AVAILABILITY(ARRTIME),
FOREIGN KEY(DEST,DEPTTIME,ARRTIME) REFERENCES FLIGHT_AVAILABILITY(DEST, DEPTTIME, ARRTIME),
FOREIGN KEY (ORIG) REFERENCES AIRPORT(AIRPORTCD)
);
```

Create Table Flight Availability

```
CREATE TABLE FLIGHT_AVAILABILITY 
(
FNO                  INTEGER NOT NULL,
ORIG               CHAR(18) NOT NULL,
DEST                CHAR(18),
DEPTTIME        DATE NOT NULL,
ARRTIME        DATE NOT NULL,
FLENGTH         INTEGER NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (FNO,ORIG,DEST,DEPTTIME,ARRTIME)
);
```

Create TableAirport

```
CREATE TABLE AIRPORT 
(
AIRPORTCD        CHAR(18) NOT NULL,
CITYID                 CHAR(18) NOT NULL,
AIRPORTNM       CHAR(18) NOT NULL,
AIRPORTTAX       CURRENCY,       
PRIMARY KEY (AIRPORTCD)
);
```

Comment: Ohh CAPS!  I love CAPS!  The error msg means that you are attempting to create a foreign key referencing a non-unique column (or columns)

Comment: Why you have so many Primary key in create table `FLIGHT_AVAILABILITY`?

Answer (score 0):

This part causes errors:

```
FOREIGN KEY (FNO) REFERENCES FLIGHT_AVAILABILITY(FNO),
FOREIGN KEY(DEST) REFERENCES FLIGHT_AVAILABILITY(DEST),
FOREIGN KEY(DEPTTIME) REFERENCES FLIGHT_AVAILABILITY(DEPTTIME),
FOREIGN KEY(ARRTIME) REFERENCES FLIGHT_AVAILABILITY(ARRTIME),
FOREIGN KEY(DEST,DEPTTIME,ARRTIME) REFERENCES FLIGHT_AVAILABILITY(DEST, DEPTTIME, ARRTIME)
```

> A foreign key constraint (also called a referential integrity
>   constraint) designates a column as the foreign key and establishes a
>   relationship between that foreign key and a specified **primary** **or
>   unique key**, called the referenced key. A composite foreign key
>   designates a combination of columns as the foreign key.

So a referenced key should be either unique or primary key.

For example:

```
FOREIGN KEY (FNO) REFERENCES FLIGHT_AVAILABILITY(FNO)
```

Referenced key = `FNO` which is not unique and is not a primary key. Although `FNO` is part of the composite `PRIMARY KEY (FNO,ORIG,DEST,DEPTTIME,ARRTIME)`, it's not unique (the combination of all the columns of the primary key is unique).

P.S. you really don't need so many columns in your primary key in FLIGHT_AVAILABILITY table. You may create a composite unique index on those columns (if it's really required) and create a NOT NULL constraint on each column. In this case you'll have the same checks as in your current composit primary key. But I don't think you need this.